# "new window" command is missing from my Windows menu in latest visual studio 16.6.2

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The Window > New Window command is missing from 16.6.2 for Visual Basic.
How can I restore it?
Is there a shortcut key?

Here is my Window menu missing the "New Window" command:
[image]

Comment: It's not clear why "Tools -> Customize" doesn't fix that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Customize > Commands > Reset All

Comment: Mo, that did not fix it.  Please see above screen shot that I just added.

Comment: @DougNull I delete most of menus then restore it again [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHTys.jpg)

Comment: I did Standard Toolbar Options > Add or Remove Buttons > Customize > Menu bar radio-button > Delete all but your list: TEAM TOOLS TEST WINDOW  HELP > Reset All (actually close and reopened before Reset All) > Add Command > set Categories  = Window > select Commands = New Window > Close ... and a New Window is now to left of Window menu.   KEY, IT'S BETTER THAN BEFORE!  YAYYY!